# Mule update to salesforce data

Tags: salesforce, mule

This will update the account in sfdc, but I need to put condition i.e where condition at the end of update, is there anyway I can handle it?. My query should be like:

> update sfdcaccount setFields WHERE client_id='#[payload.get('id')]'

I have seen some example, select the query with were condition, if satisfies then update. Can we directly update based on condition?

Mule Flow:

```
<sfdc:update config-ref="SFDC__DevInt" type="Account" doc:name="Salesforce">
   <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
</sfdc:update>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your client_id is an external id ([Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm)) you can fetch the object, remove id/any other external keys and then set the client_id and it will update the object.

Do note that all fields may be replaced if you use the original fetched object. Perhaps you should setup your own input map before updating so you won't change any field/future field by mistake.